# Arccotx definite integral

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals

[image]

Need help with.the question. The solution is given but I have no idea how they have broken into intervals. Would love some help.

Comment: Try graphing it: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/udtn3iwgpb

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\cot^{-1}(x)$ is a decreasing function on the entire domain, which implies that for $x \in (-\infty$; $\infty$) your resulting value will decrease from $\pi$ to $0$.

Now, remember, that $\cot^{-1}(\cot(x)) = x$ shifted by required amount of $\pi$ to be in the $(0;\pi)$. Since $0, 1, 2$ and $3$ are inside the $(0;\pi$), no shifts are needed and the result is basically $\cot^{-1}(\cot(x)) = x$ for $x \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ which lets you figure out the breakpoints for the shifts and thus the points of partition of your integral.

And the last thing: $\cot(x)$ is a decreasing function, so $\cot(3) < \cot(2) < \cot(1)$

Comment: I'm sorry, but why are we thinking in terms of arc cot(cot x)? I am still not absolutely sure of the solution. Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: $cot(3.01) = -7.55$, $cot(3) = -7.016$. $\cot^{-1}(-7.55) = 3.01$, $\cot^{-1}(-7.016) = 3$. Roughly, of course. But this is the idea. Before you cross 3, the value will be 3 with the [ ] operator, and then once you cross 3, the [ ] operator will return 2 untill you cross 2, etc.