# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \lfloor\cot^{-1}x\rfloor\,dx$ from $0$ to $2 \pi$.

Tags: calculus

Evaluate $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \lfloor\cot^{-1}x\rfloor\,dx$ from $0$ to $2 \pi$.  Where $\lfloor{}\cdot{}\rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer function.

Here $x$ varies from $0$ to $2 \pi$, so

$\cot^{-1}0 > \cot^{-1}x > \cot^{-1}2 \pi$

$\infty > \cot^{-1}x > \cot^{-1}2 \pi$

Now 
$\int_{\cot1}^{ 2\pi} \lfloor\cot^{-1}x\rfloor\,dx + \int_{0}^{\cot1}\lfloor\cot^{-1}x\rfloor\,dx$

The first part of integral is clearly zero, how to evaluate second part?

Comment: @egreg you edited the question correctly.

Comment: @Mathsaddict The symbol $\lfloor{}\cdot{}\rfloor$ is more commonly used than $[{}\cdot{}]$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3076606/arccotx-definite-integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$0\le x\le\cot1$$

$$\dfrac\pi2\ge\cot^{-1}x\ge1\implies\left\lfloor\cot^{-1}x\right\rfloor=1$$